# Test large number of concurrent TCP connections

Tags: networking, tcp, connection, limit

I have developed an HTTP server application and a client for it. They are communicating over WebSocket. The nature of the application is to keep a long-living WebSocket connection for real-time communication. Now I want to find out how many concurrent connections the system can handle and how much memory and CPU time it needs for normal operation with many connected users.

The application is written in C# using .NET 8.0 with async code. One of the server variants I'm evaluating is ASP.NET Core, the other is a self-made one. Everything is AOT-compiled to native code for maximum resource efficiency. I can try this on Windows 11 x64 and Ubuntu Linux x64. And I did.

The main problem is that I cannot open enough connections. When I stay below 1000 connections and don't open them too quickly, it's all fine. With a little waiting I could even get 10 000 connections (but not much more) from one Windows machine to another over the LAN (both have plenty of RAM), with many times not reaching high numbers again. But from what I've read, there should also be the possibility of more than a million connections.

The second try is now on a fresh Ubuntu Server 23.10 installation with 4 GB RAM. It couldn't even get near that number. I found an article that explains how to edit /etc/security/limits.conf and now `ulimit -Sn` shows 1048576. Yet the client gets stuck after around 800 connections (to the local host name). Restarting both server and client process doesn't change that.

Also changing the server to listen on 100 ports and connecting to all of them round-robin in the client application (which should extend source-port-related limits by factor 100) doesn't change anything. I verified that all server ports are being used.

(Update: I also tried with plain TCP connections now, leaving out anything HTTP. Same problem. I cannot open more than 1000 TCP connections on a Linux machine. Using a single server port or 100 doesn't matter. The limit spreads across multiple client machines trying to do a part of the connections. So I guess the server is the limitation.)

Now I'm asking how it's possible to open a million TCP connections to a locally hosted server. I can spin up multiple Ubuntu instances in VMs if one isn't enough. Is there some settings file I need to change? I'm not interested in safe production settings, this is a local test only.

Comment: "_(I'm also aware that I should use multiple IP addresses if using a single client system because of 64k IP ports._" No. The connection is identified by both the source and destination IP and TCP addresses. Keeping the same destination (server) IP and TCP addresses, you could theoretically have `281,474,976,710,656` connections for the total number of IP and TCP source combinations `2^32*2^16`.

Comment: Currently my server has a single IP address and listen port and one client has a single source IP address, which leaves the source port for possible combinations. That is 65535 but only very few seem to be normally usable. (I could also add more listen ports to my server.) Anyway, I hit greatly varying different limits in practice and want to overcome them.

Comment: @RonMaupin But if testing from a single client he will run out of source ports < 64k. Using multiple client IP addresses will fix that.

Comment: Yes, from a single source IP address. There is a persistent myth that servers can only handle `65,535` (port `0` cannot be used) connections, and that is simply incorrect. even with a single server IP address, the number of possible connections is far larger than any server could handle, and it just increases with multiple IP addresses on a server.

Comment: I changed my server to listen on 100 ports and the client to use all of them round-robin. Should extend my limits by factor 100, but doesn't at all. Still ~700 connections locally or remotely, then it hangs.

Comment: @RonMaupin I’m talking about the single client., which is what the question is about.

Comment: You can have multiple addresses on a single host.